# Extract string after specific data occurrence

Tags: sql, string

I have the following string which varies in length depending on database and table name:

[servername].[databasename].[dbo].[tablename.csv]

I would like to extract only the table name after "[dbo]." and before ".csv]".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [tablename here you go!
SELECT
 LEFT(name, len(name) -4)
FROM
    sys.tables
WHERE
 name LIKE '%.csv'

Comment: Hi deterministicFail, thank you for the quick reply, however, the result I get when executing is '[servername].[databasename].[dbo].[tablename.' This only excludes the last part which is 'csv]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @str varchar(200) = '[servername].[tablename].[dbo].[tablename.csv]'

select substring(@str,(PATINDEX('%dbo%',@str)+6), 
(PATINDEX('%.csv%', @str) - (PATINDEX('%dbo%',@str)+6)))
```